# mod_rewrite redirects to www.example.com// when trying to access example.com

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have a VPS on which I'm trying to setup multiple websites. For one of them, with the current set of rules (below), accessing

```
hxxp://example.com
```

sends me to

```
hxxp://www.example.com// [note the two //]
```

My httpd.conf looks like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

[other VirtualHosts]

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
ServerName www.example.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<directory /var/www/html/example.com>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(.*)/?$ /showitem.php?j=$1 [NC]

</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: +1 The Request URI includes the leading slash.

Comment: That would be a reason to use RewriteRule /(.*) and match it in the target, not the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.*` **includes** the slash that is already in the URL.  You then send a redirect to `http://www.example.com/$1` which includes another slash.

One of the following will fix your problem:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will not happen inside a `<Directory >` block or in a `.htaccess` file because in both those cases there is no leading slash on the URI.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get rid of that double / by letting the regex part of the directive "eat" it:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of the *hxxp* protocol.

Your virtualhost answers to both example.com and **www**.example.com requests.

The fix is simple: Add a separate vhost for www.example.com and remove the ServerAlias from example.com.

Then Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/

Note the prevalence of the slash on both source and target - that is the mistake you made.

I'm not going to show you how to fix the rewiterule, since you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Umm - that's because I'm a new user and making more than two links like http://asdf.com isnt allowed

Comment: I don't know what that means. Don't use rewrites when anything else will do the job.